# How to get response body of sync process when there are sync and async processors in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, httpresponse

I want to intercept and get response body of sync processing.
If I try this, my controllers - both with sync and async processors work correctly, but I receive nothing from sync response in else clause

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    if (request.isAsyncStarted()) {
        //Some code
    } else {
        byte[] responseArray = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
        String responseString = new String(responseArray, responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
        System.out.println("response = " + responseString);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
    
    ThreadContext.clearMap();
}
```

If I try this, I receive the body of response in else clause, but async process does not release http thread

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

if (request.isAsyncStarted()) {
//Some code
} else {
byte[] responseArray = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
String responseString = new String(responseArray, responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
System.out.println("response = " + responseString);
responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
}
ThreadContext.clearMap();
}
```